# Convert a jQuery AJAX call to curl instead to put within a Magento observer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, curl

I have a Magento observer that I want to use some curl with - essentially I want to use the very same request as the jQuery AJAX call below but convert this into a cURL event within my observer function.

```
        $('#org_search_term').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('rp/organisation/search', array('_secure' => true)) ?>',
        paramName:'term',
        minChars: 3,
        deferRequestBy: 500,
        dataType: 'json',
        transformResult: function (response) {
            var results = { suggestions:[] };

            if (!response.totalRecords)
                return false;

            $.each(response.items, function(i, item){
                results.suggestions.push({
                    value: item.organisation_name+', '+item.street+', '+item.town+', '+item.county+', '+item.postcode+', '+item.country,
                    data:  item.organisation_id
                });
            });

            return results;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry if i've misunderstood, why do you want to send HTTP request to your own server if you're not using AJAX. Could you not just load the model/collection to get the data you need on the server side? Much faster that way.

Comment: that does make more sense to be honest - im still learning the whole MAGEnto :-)

Comment: No worries. In that case, work out which controller is getting called from the route rp/organisation/search. The controller code will probably load a collection model to get the data returned by the Ajax controller method. You just need to load that same collection model in your observer. e.g. Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?  I mean, I don't think there is anything special about your ajax request.

```
<?php

$opts = array(
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'My-Magento-Observer',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => False,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
  ),
  CURLOPT_URL => $this->getUrl('rp/organisation/search', array('_secure' => true)),
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS = array(
    'paramName' => 'term',
  ),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($opts);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
  $error = curl_error($ch);
  echo $error;
}
else {
  echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: decided to use an observer in the end - but will accept your answer as that appears to be right :)